# Response from a server, how to loop through each element

Tags: javascript

I have an response formatted like this:

```
[{"url" : "www.link.com"}, ..., {"url" : "www.link.com"}]
```

How do I access each link and do something with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular `for` loop and access the properties with `dot` notation

```js
var urls = [{
  "url": "www.link.com"
}, {
  "url": "www.link.com"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  console.log(urls[i].url);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. The response text is in the format show in my question, how do I save that into an array and loop through it (you already showed).

Comment: @safaiyeh, what does the response text look like?

Comment: "[{"url" : "www.link.com"}, ..., {"url" : "www.link.com"}]"

Comment: @safaiyeh, right, that is already an array and the code snippet in my answer uses an array like that. Maybe I am misunderstanding exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: when I use your code, it returns "undefined", it treats the response text as a string instead of an array.

Comment: @safaiyeh, it is working when you run the code snippet in the answer. Can you reproduce the problem with a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: use `JSON.parse(str)` to parse your string into an array